# ReactJS App gives cannot find module 'webpack' [ReactJS app in cjs/loader.js] --

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules, sass-loader

I found a few links/threads relating to this, but they are mostly on angular. And the problem I am having is related to ReactJS.

The main error is:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
```

The Require stack is such:

```
Require stack:
- E:\REACT\MySite\protik-site\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\REACT\MySite\protik-site\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:36:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'E:\\REACT\\MySite\\protik-site\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
```

The trouble piece is in the piece of code in css file.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Icons;
    /*src: url(../fonts/open-iconic/open-iconic.eot);*/
    src: url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.eot);
    src: url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.eot?#iconic-sm) format('embedded-opentype'),url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.woff) format('woff'),url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.ttf) format('truetype'),url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.otf) format('opentype'),url(http://localhost:3000/open-iconic.svg#iconic-sm) format('svg');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```

I detected, all those src urls are causing the problem.

I did run ***npm ls webpack*** at one point and it showed that webpack is installed in two paths - the main nodemodules and also inside react-scripts. Currently, right at this point in time, I have none. I have deleted both manually.
Those familiar with Angular would know that we could write explicit loader rules in the module.exports of the webpack.js file of the project. Funny enough, in React apps there is no such file created. I have no idea whether I should create one specifically and write some code in there, or if there is some other clean, precise solution to whatever fracas I may be having.

Can you tell me exactly where is the grief? What modification exactly is required? Studying the require stack I posted, is it possible for you to pinpoint the problem? If you need farther info on my ***node_modules*** status or any other file, would be glad to share.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project was created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), because it uses [react-scripts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts) which is part of it.

[react-scripts has a dependency to webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts?activeTab=dependencies) and the output of your error tells us, that react-scripts tries to run the start script which requires the missing webpack module.

Did you

> npm install

before starting the app?

**Outcome after comments:**

correctly install open-iconic:

- either download the [vendor-css file](https://github.com/iconic/open-iconic/blob/master/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css) and add it to your project and import it into your source css (not recommended, but possible)
- just add it via cdn to your project e.g. add this line to any css file in use (or create a specific css file for vendor imports and import it that within your App.css) `@import
  url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css');`
- add it via cdn to your index.html with this line:
  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/open-iconic/1.1.1/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">`

Build should correctly work.

Your .css file includes paths to localhost which probably caused the break.

Comment: yes, I created it with npx create-react-app blablaabla. Before starting the app I straightway did npm start.           @ndeufemia. Worked fine before I added the reference to the specific css file import "./styles/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css"; That one contains those font-face src urls.

Comment: can you spot anything from the [require stack]. pl node: currently I have cleared webpack from both paths, to avoid any trouble. It's all clean. What next??

Comment: you shouldn't clear any modules manually, either they are required as dependency or within your own package.json. I recommend to delete the node_modules/ folder and do a npm i from scratch.

Comment: Did you add the above mentioned file "./styles/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" on your own?

Comment: hi, ok, that I will. Fresh install the entire node_modules from scratch.
Yeah, I added the css file on my own cuz it is part of a theme I am using. @ndeufemia  . What about it?

Comment: I added that css file import in my App.js imports section. Several other such css files too cuz they are part of a website theme and I need them.   @ndeufemia  Anything wrong with what I did there?  OK just saw your latest EDIT. let me read and understand what it requires me to do.

Comment: I don't have a index.html created in my ReactJS app project structure, wrt your 3rd point mention.  @ndeufemia Also, WRT point 2, it requires a .TS file in the project, .js file won't do.

Comment: the index.html is always created but placed within your dist/ or public/ folder.
Your index.js aquires your App.js and renders your React Application to the html element with the ID "root". You can find the #root element within your index.html.
This means, the body of index.html is filled by your app, don't add anything there.
Only use the index.html for importing vendor stuff / stuff that should always be there, like the favicon, which is normally done automatically for you by webpack (when using react-create-app) within the <head>

Comment: nope. nothing's working. After fresh install of npm modules, this is what I get---> 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command. I will be trying a few things of my own. Will revert if I find a way out.  @ndeufemia

Comment: check if your package.json contains "react-scripts", if not, do `npm install --save react-scripts`

Comment: Did you try to install open-iconic via one option that I provided you instead of including this css file?